# need to open a link in different browsers from a phonegap app

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, cordova

I want to open a website link in all the available browsers in phone. I have this requirement in which a link should be opened in chrome, mozilla, IE etc. I need to build this using phonegap.

Comment: That doesnt sound like a very realistic requirement... whats the real reason?

Comment: I am trying to make an app which will use for manual testing of different urls. We get requests from customers to check the urls in chrome, IE and different browsers and based on that we have to type and open the urls in different browsers. I am planning to make an app that will save all the urls and will have different icon for different browsers. If one has to open a url in chrome, a chrome link can be clicked and the url will open in chrome browser, same will be the case with IE and other different browsers.

Answer (score 0):

```
Open all website link in browser from app 

window.open(your_url, '_system');
```